# Sinon how to unit test a non exported private functionality?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dependency-injection, sinon

Im really new to unit testing, im trying to mock `aws.ses` method using `sinon.js`, but my concern is how im calling the `sesConstructor` method. Since it is not getting exported from `ses.js`, ive declared a `sesConstructor` method inside the test suite.

Would really appreciate if anyone could tell me whether this is a complete anti-pattern and whether there are any other better solution for this (without using 'rewire' module)

ses.js

```js
let ses = {};

const sesConstructor = () => {
  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: configurations.AWS_CONFIG.ACCESSKEYID,
    secretAccessKey: configurations.AWS_CONFIG.SECRECTACCESSKEY,
    region: configurations.AWS_CONFIG.REGION
  });
  ses = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: "2010-12-01" });
};

export const sendTemplatedEmail = (emailTo, templateName, templateData) => {
  sesConstructor();

  const params = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: emailTo
    },
    Source: process.env.emailSource,
    Template: templateName,
    TemplateData: JSON.stringify(templateData)
  };

  return ses.sendTemplatedEmail(params).promise();
};

export default { sendTemplatedEmail };
```

ses.test.js

```js
describe("SES", () => {
  const emailTo = ["test@gmail.com"];
  const templateName = "template";
  const templateData = "test";
  process.env.emailSource = "test@gamil.com";
  const sendEmail = sendTemplatedEmail(emailTo, templateName, templateData);

  it("should return a promise", () => {
    expect(sendEmail).to.be.a("promise");
  });

  describe("sesConstructor", () => {
    it("should call AWS SES", () => {
      const sesConstructor = data => {
        const ses = new AWS.SES(data); // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
      };

      const mockAWS = sinon.mock(AWS);

      mockAWS
        .expects("SES")
        .once()
        .withArgs({
          apiVersion: "2010-12-01"
        })
        .returns(true);

      sesConstructor({ apiVersion: "2010-12-01" });

      mockAWS.verify();
      mockAWS.restore();
    });

   
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your `sendTemplatedEmail` function does one more thing that is not indicated in name: initialize transport. And it's hard dependency of `sendTemplatedEmail`. You need something to do with this dependency to made it more testable, possible solutions:

1) pass transport instance as an argument. Consider the next:

```
const sesConstructor = () => {
  //...
  return AWS.SES(...);
};

export const sendTemplatedEmail = (emailTo, templateName, templateData, ses = sesConstructor()) => {
  const params = {...}
  return ses.send(...);
}
```

In this case you add new param to your `sendTemplatedEmail` ses instance, which by default is got from `sesConstructor()` - this allows you to pass stub in your test, and easily test it.

You can also put instance in `closure`, if it's suitable for you:

```
export const sendTemplatedEmail = (ses = sesConstructor()) => (emailTo, templateName, templateData) => {
  const params = {...}
  return ses.send(...)
}
```

then you'll use it:

```
sendTemplatedEmail()('some@person.com'...)
```

and in test you'll pass stub into it, and easily test it:

```
sendTemplatedEmail(stubOfSes)('some@person.com'...)
```

Google `dependency injection` if you need more theory about it.

2) Export it. Why don't you export the object with 2 props: `sesConstructor` and `sendTemplatedEmail`?

```
let emailSender = {

  sesConstructor: () => {
    //...
    return AWS.SES(...);
  },

  sendTemplatedEmail: (emailTo, templateName, templateData) => {

    // ...
    return this.sesConstructor().sendTemplatedEmail(...);
  };

export default emailSender;
```

In this case, in your test file you just need to stub `sesConstructor` method of imported object, and get it easily testable.

I don't think it's full list on how it could be organized, but it's the directions I'd work with it.

Hope it helps.